# Как найти в Wordpress нужный хук

Tags: wordpress

Как найти в Wordpress требуемый хук, чтобы подцепить на него свою функцию. Может быть, существует какой-то принцип поиска, подскажите хоть что-то по методологии поиска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживая ответ SeVlad, добавлю, что методология поиска актуальных хуков всегда одна - глобальный поиск по файлам ядра. Делать это на сервере через `grep`, открывая потом файлы один за другим, - крайне неудобно.

Надо иметь локальную копию всех файлов ядра и плагинов (если и в них нужно искать хуки) и вести поиск с помощью современной IDE, например, PhpStorm. IDE индексирует файлы проекта и проводит поиск мгновенно, с выдачей кратких результатов в окне поиска, откуда можно сразу открывать файлы для дальнейшего изучения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно действовать иначе - открыть нужную вам функцию в ядре, например, `wp_insert_post()` и смотреть её код на наличие хуков, которые она вызывает. Если внутри неё есть какие-то вызываемые функции, перейти к ним можно через `Ctrl+Click`,  а вернуться назад через `Ctrl+Alt+Left`.

В общем, IDE - наиболее быстрый способ, чтобы что-то понять в коде ядра.

Answer (score 0):

> Как найти в Wordpress требуемый хук, чтобы подцепить на него свою
> функцию. Может быть, существует какой-то принцип поиска, подскажите
> хоть что-то по методологии поиска.

[Оф. список хуков](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/) и [на русском](https://wp-kama.ru/hooks) (может быть не всё актуально)

Названия же интуитивно понятны. `add`- добавить, `get` - получить, `user`(s) - пользователь(ли), `post` - запись и тд.